# How to convert CFDataRef into NSData?

Tags: objective-c

I have `CFDataRef` and I want to convert it into `NSData`.

```
CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGImageGetDataProvider(screenShot);
CFDataRef data = CGDataProviderCopyData(dataProvider);
CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);
NSString *imagePathLocation = [destinationPath stringByAppendingString:[@"/" stringByAppendingString:DesktopImage]];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager]createFileAtPath: imagePathLocation contents:nil attributes:nil];
fileHandleForImage = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:imagePathLocation];
NSData * data1 = (NSData *)data;
[fileHandleForImage writeData:data1];
```

When I typecast (`NSData * data1 = (NSData *)data`) it image gets corrupted.

Can anyoone help?

Comment: I think you mean CFDataRef. I can't find any references to CGDataRef in Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 28):

It's toll-free bridged, so you just have to cast it.

```
NSData *myData = (__bridge NSData *)myCFDataRef;
```

Comment: You just need to add the appropriate ownership keyword. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW3 and http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html (search for "Toll-Free Bridging") for details.

Comment: Nowadays you need to add `__bridge` to the cast `(__bridge NSData *)myCFDataRef;`

Comment: If its not allowed in ARC, how do you do it in ARC?

Answer (score 17):

As @KrisMarkel said, you just have to transfer ownership to ARC like so:

Like so to transfer ownership:

```
NSData* data1 = (__bridge_transfer NSData*) data;
```

else to use the reference without transferring ownership:

```
NSData* data2 = (__bridge NSData*) data;
```